# Trying to create custom function on google sheets to check if something is paid and add it to a total

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, custom-function

So i'm trying to create a custom function on google sheets that will see a value, check to see if the next cell says 'yes' (which means that value has already been paid), and if 'yes' is there it should take that value and add it to a total and return that total, but I keep getting '0' as a return value. Here's my code:

This is what I tried:

```
function totalStatus(input) {
  let total= 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {

    for(let y = 0; y < input[i].length; y++) {
      if (input[i][y] !== '' && input[i][y + 1] === 'yes') {
        input[i][y] += total;
      }
    }
  }
  return total;
}
```

and kept getting '0' as a return.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your goal, when you modify `input[i][y] += total;` to `total += input[i][y];`, will that be your expected result? If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: Yes, that did it! I didn't realize the order was wrong there. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not modifying total, you should have `total += input[i][y]`. What you are doing is adding `total` to `input[i][y]`, which in turn does nothing, because `total = 0`.

Comment: Thank you for that! I did not realize I was doing that.. Sorry, still new to programming. But a big thank you!